# Dynamic react route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently learning the dynamic react route. In my sample code, I have different buttons for each work. When the button is clicked, it must render the `WorkDetails` component. However, it's not doing that even when I manually change the URL slug. I'm having a hard time figuring out what went wrong.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-routes-budulp?file=/src/App.js

This is the routes in my App component

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/works" element={<Work data={data} />}>
      <Route path=":slug" element={<WorkDetails />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In my `Work` component, each button is surrounded with `Link`. For the path, I used the `slug` from my array of objects in data file.

```
const Work = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Works</h1>
      {data.map(({ id, name, slug }) => {
        return (
          <div key={id} id={id}>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <Link to={slug}>
              <button>Work Details</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

data.js

```
let works = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Work 1",
    slug: "work-one",
    subtopics: [
      {
        title: "About the project",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Process",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Result",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Work 2",
    slug: "work-two",
    subtopics: [
      {
        title: "About the project",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Process",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Result",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Work 3",
    slug: "work-three",
    subtopics: [
      {
        title: "About the project",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Process",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Result",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Work 4",
    slug: "work-four",
    subtopics: [
      {
        title: "About the project",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Process",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      },
      {
        title: "Result",
        description:
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar. Curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing."
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

On my `WorkDetails` component, I used the `useParams()` which I expect to return the `slug`. Then, I used the `slug` to find the object with the same `slug`. The state will then be updated with the found object.

```
const WorkDetails = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();

  // Find the object with the same slug as the params.
  const [work, setWork] = useState(null);
  let findWork = data.find((d) => d.slug === slug);
  if (findWork) {
    setWork(findWork);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/works">
        <button>Back to Works</button>
      </Link>
      <h1>{work.name}</h1>
      {work.subtopic.map((topic) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h2>{topic.title}</h2>
            <p>{topic.description}</p>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in app.js to this

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/works" element={<Work data={data} />} />
        <Route path="/works/:slug" element={<WorkDetails />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

and this line  `<Link to={slug}>`to this  `<Link to={`${slug}`}>`

and work details to this

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "./data";

const WorkDetails = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  console.log(";", slug);

  // Find the object with the same slug as the params.
  const [work, setWork] = useState({});
  let findWork = data.find((d) => d.slug === slug);
  console.log("ll", findWork);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (findWork) {
      setWork(findWork);
    }

  }, [findWork])
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/works">
        <button>Back to Works</button>
      </Link>
      <h1>{work?.name}</h1>
      {work?.subtopics?.map((topic) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h2>{topic.title}</h2>
            <p>{topic.description}</p>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WorkDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your workDetail file as

```
    const WorkDetails = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  // Find the object with the same slug as the params.
  const [work, setWork] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
  let findWork = data.find((d) => d.slug === slug);
    if (findWork) {
      setWork(findWork);
    }
  }, [findWork])

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/works">
        <button>Back to Works</button>
      </Link>
      <h1>{work.name}</h1>
      {work.subtopic?.map((topic) => {
        return (
          <>
            <h2>{topic.title}</h2>
            <p>{topic.description}</p>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. the sequencing of the routes is not correct, its should be from specific to generic.
2. Also in the work details you are setting the variable incorrectly.

I have tweaked your example for you, see below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-routes-forked-7j026p

Comment: Hi. I have a question, what does the Route does in the Work component?

Comment: It works but because you have a more generic route before a specific route, so it was picking up a generic one. I would recommend you have look at this documentation it will clear a few things up. https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/recursive-paths

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

The `WorkDetails` component is rendered on a ***nested*** route, so in order to be rendered the parent `Work` component rendered on `"/works"` necessarily needs to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into.

An additional issue that is that the `WorkDetails` is issuing state updates as an unintentional side-effect. In fact the `work` state is completely unnecessary since it's able to be derived from the current `slug` route path parameter value and the `data` array of work items. It's a React anti-pattern to store derived "state" in React state. Filter/find the matching work item from the `data` array, and if necessary, memoize the value via the `useMemo` hook instead of storing in any state.

## Solution

### Layout & Nested Routes

If you want to use `Work` as a layout route then it should render also an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/works" element={<Work />}>
      <Route path=":slug" element={<WorkDetails />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
import { Link, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { data } from '../path/to/data';

const Work = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Works</h1>
        {data.map(({ id, name, slug }) => (
          <div key={id} id={id}>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <Link to={slug}>
              <button>Work Details</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render element here
    </>
  );
};
```

### Regular Routes

If you want to `Work` and `WorkDetails` to render as two separate routes and components they un-nest the routes. No `Outlet` component is required to render `WorkDetails`.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/works">
      <Route index element={<Work />} />               // <-- "/works"
      <Route path=":slug" element={<WorkDetails />} /> // <-- "/works/:slug"
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

### `WorkDetails` should compute and render derived "state"

The `WorkDetails` component shouldn't store the derived work item value into local state. It should instead directly compute and render the searched result.

Example:

```
const WorkDetails = () => {
  const { slug } = useParams();

  // Find the object with the same slug as the params.
  const findWork = data.find((d) => d.slug === slug);

  if (!findWork) {
    return null; // <-- or some "Not Found" fallback UI
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/works">
        <button>Back to Works</button>
      </Link>
      <h1>{work.name}</h1>
      {work.subtopic.map((topic) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={topic.title}> // <-- don't forget React key
            <h2>{topic.title}</h2>
            <p>{topic.description}</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If the derived state needs to be memoized then use the `useMemo` hook:

```
const findWork = useMemo(() => data.find((d) => d.slug === slug), [slug]);
```